# Unwanted space between logo and title in titlepage

Tags: spacing, graphics, titles

I have a problem that I can't resolve.
I already did a title page using LaTeX but it contains many spaces between the logo of my school and the name of the school.
This is my code please if any person can help me

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\color{blue}
\bf {REPUBLIQUE TUNISIENNE \\
MINISTERE DE L'ENSEIGNEMENT SUPERIEUR,\\
DE LA RECHERCHE SCIENTIFIQUE ET DE LA TECHNOLOGIE \\
UNIVERSITE TUNIS EL MANAR }
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{logo}
}
\centerline{
\textcolor{myblue}{\bf \normalsize{INSTITUT SUPERIEUR D'INFORMATIQUE}}
}

\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\color{black}
\bf \Large{M\'EMOIRE DE MAST\`ERE}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\color{black} \normalsize \bf{{Pr\'esent\'e en vue de l'obtention du \\
Dipl\^ome de mast\`ere de recherche en G\'enie logiciel \\
Option:Logiciels et Syst\`emes Critiques }}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\hspace{4cm}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{center}



\end{center}
\end{minipage}

{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\begin{center}


 \fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont 
\bfseries{Protection de la vie priv\'ee dans les r\'eseaux sociaux : 
principalement Facebook}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Elabor\'e Par: Gherib Boutheina}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Encadr\'e par: Nawel Ben Salem Grati}
\vspace{1cm}

{\large \bf{Ann\'ee Universitaire:2011-2012}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thank you for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), but please enhance it and make it a compilable example.  A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).  I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Note that a `{` or `}` at the end of a source line will cause a space. You should add a `%` to comment out the line end to avoid this space. I mean the `\centerline{` etc.

Comment: Note that `\bf` is outdated. You should use `\textbf{<bold text>}` or `{\bfseries <cold text>}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the relevant part of your code is this, isn't?

```
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{logo}%
}
\centerline{%
\textcolor{myblue}{\bf \normalsize{INSTITUT SUPERIEUR D'INFORMATIQUE}}%
}
```

From this code, I can see no reason for having a big space between the logo and the text which follows, so I guess that the space is indeed "inside" the logo. Can you check with an external tool if the logo contains some kind of white margin around?

If so, clip it with some graphic edition tool before including, or use the options `trim=a b c d` and `clip` of `\includegraphics`, where `a b c d` are the amounts to remove from the left, bottom, right and top of the original box, respectively.

```
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,clip,trim=left bottom right top]{logo}%
}
```

Comment: yes what you have said is right the space is indeed inside the logo.

Comment: when i put this \centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,clip,trim= <1cm><1cm><1cm><1cm>]{logo}%
} these errors are generated ! Argument of \Gread@parse@vp has an extra }.<inserted text>\par }! Paragraph ended before \Gread@parse@vp was complete.<to be read again>\par }! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.<recently read> } }! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{center}! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Com

Comment: Remove `<>` around dimensions, i.e: `\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,clip,trim=1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm]{logo}`

Comment: thank you very much with your suggestion i can resolve my problem that i was blocked in for many days so thank you very much for you.